# Django Rest + Jinja2: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, jinja2

I am currently developing a Django website using the Jinja2 template engine using the [django-jinja](https://niwibe.github.io/django-jinja/) package. As the website will need a JSON api I thought of using the [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (DRF).

Everything worked nicely before using DRF, using class based views that inherited from django's class based views (TemplateView, ListView, ...).

**Django Rest Framework Part**

So I started including DRF to the website by creating Serializers and Routers. My settings for DRF are the following:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}
```

My serializers are the following

```
class ItemCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ItemCategory
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'slug')

class ItemImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ItemImage
        fields = ('id', 'file',)

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    categories = ItemCategorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    photos = ItemImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = (
            'id', 'owner', 'name', 'categories', 'photos', 'price', 'quantity',
            'urgent', 'available', 'condition', 'boxing', 'description',
            'start_date', 'end_date', 'created_at', 'modified_at'
        )
```

And my urls.py are the following:

```
router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'', ItemViewSet)

urlpatters = router.urls
```

I created one view to test the system:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Item.objects.all().select_related('owner').prefetch_related('categories', 'photos')
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsOwnerOrReadOnly,
    )

    def list(self, request):
        self.template_name = 'item/list.jinja'
        return super(ItemViewSet, self).list(request)
```

**django-jinja Part**

My template settings are such as:

```
TEMPLATES = [

    {
        'BACKEND': 'django_jinja.backend.Jinja2',
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            #'match_regex': "*\.jinja$",
            'match_extension': '.jinja',
            'newstyle_gettext': True,
            'autoescape': True,
            'auto_reload': DEBUG,
            'constants': {
                'STATIC_URL': STATIC_URL,
                'timezone': timezone, # timezone is django.utils.timezone
            },
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
            'extensions': [
                'jinja2.ext.do',
                'jinja2.ext.loopcontrols',
                'jinja2.ext.with_',
                'jinja2.ext.i18n',
                'jinja2.ext.autoescape',
                'django_jinja.builtins.extensions.CsrfExtension',
                'django_jinja.builtins.extensions.CacheExtension',
                'django_jinja.builtins.extensions.TimezoneExtension',
                'django_jinja.builtins.extensions.UrlsExtension',
                'django_jinja.builtins.extensions.StaticFilesExtension',
                'django_jinja.builtins.extensions.DjangoFiltersExtension',

                'jdj_tags.extensions.DjangoStatic',
                'jdj_tags.extensions.DjangoI18n',
                'jdj_tags.extensions.DjangoStatic',
                'jdj_tags.extensions.DjangoUrl',
            ],
        }
    },

    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**Settings Part**

In my `settings.py`, the `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` look like that:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'pytz',
    'django_extensions',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'django_jinja',
    'django_jinja.contrib._humanize',
    'django_jinja.contrib._easy_thumbnails',

    'rest_framework',

    'mysite.item',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

)
```

Now that you can see the whole system the problem I have is that when I load the page at `/items/` which calls the `.list(request)` method of the `ItemViewSet`, I get the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/items/

Django Version: 1.8.1
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'pytz',
 'django_extensions',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'django_jinja',
 'django_jinja.contrib._humanize',
 'django_jinja.contrib._easy_thumbnails',
 'rest_framework',
 'mysite.item',
 'mysite.person')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  164.                 response = response.render()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  158.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in rendered_content
  59.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in render
  169.         return template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_jinja/backend.py" in render
  66.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py" in render
  972.         vars = dict(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: ValueError at /items/
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
```

So I edited the file at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py` and printed `args` and `kwargs` in order to better understand what was going on:

when printing `args` using `print`:

```
([{
        'False': False,
        'None': None,
        'True': True
    },
    [OrderedDict(  ... here were all serialized objects returned  )], {}
], )
```

and when printing `kwargs` it simply returned `{}`

So yeah basically if anyone has any idea of what is happening or what I could do to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance, Thomas

**EDIT 1**

The first major finding is that when doing a normal request, `args` is a tuple containing a flat `dict`, whereas in the request using DRF, `args` is a tuple  containing a `RequestContext` object.

So obviously I try to call `args.flatten()` to get a normal dict object. Now this method throws a similar error: `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 16; 2 is required`.

This error occurs in the code inside `django.template.context.RequestContext.flatten()` which is

```
def flatten(self):
        """
        Returns self.dicts as one dictionary
        """
        flat = {}
        for d in self.dicts:
            flat.update(d)  # <-- Exception occurs at this point
        return flat
```

I'll try to gather more information in order to solve this issue

**EDIT 2**

I realised the REST framework instantiates the RequestContext inside the `render` method of the TemplateHTMLRenderer, so obviously that breaks the system because Jinja2 expects a dict and not a RequestContext. Trying to write a fix now

**EDIT 3: FIXED**

Okay so the only way I could see in order to fix this was to write my own REST Renderer and so I wrote a JinjaTemplateRenderer that I will post on github and try to merge with the project. I will post here soon

Comment: Considering this is an issue with your template, it might be useful to include that in your question (the template code).

Comment: Well basically I tried with an empty template and with a template containing html, and both returned the same error.

I think the error comes from the fact that the rest-framework does not provide all the elements that a normal TemplateResponse provides, and jinja does not like it. The error occurs when jinja tries to render the template from the context, and not when parsing the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by writing my own renderer, here a [JinjaTemplateRenderer](https://github.com/tgdn/django-rest-framework/blob/a21ee8ea458a252c9135bba8ce716f7bfde98037/rest_framework/renderers.py#L203)

Although this is not really working in the end, many problems with it, I will just go back to using normal class based views instead of the REST framework as it does not satisfy my needs.